# How to obtain the basic blocks that are reachable from basic block A?

Tags: llvm

I want to know all of the basic blocks that a basic block can reach.
How might I go about doing this?

```
#include "llvm/IR/CFG.h"
BasicBlock *BB = ...;
for (BasicBlock *Pred : predecessors(BB)) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk through the successors of successors (and so on), e.g.:

```
std::unordered_set<BasicBlock *> reachable;
std::queue<BasicBlock *> worklist;
worklist.insert(BB);
while (!worklist.empty()) {
  BasicBlock *front = worklist.front();
  worklist.pop();
  for (BasicBlock *succ : successors(front)) {
    if (reachable.count(succ) == 0) {
       /// We need the check here to ensure that we don't run 
       /// infinitely if the CFG has a loop in it
       /// i.e. the BB reaches itself directly or indirectly
       worklist.push(succ);
       reachable.push(succ);
    }
  }
}
```

If I didn't make any mistakes, then you'll get the all the reachable basic blocks in the end of the while loop :)